# If the message is a reply, bot should get id of a user

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am doing a bot-moderator. I am doing a command 'ban'. if I reply to somebody's message by typing `/ban` bot should get its id and restrict him.
my code now:

```py
@bot.messsage_handler(commands=['ban'])

def ban(message):

    #here I should get the id of a user which I replied in Telegram
    #then bot should restrict him.
```

PyTelegramBotApi

python 3.7

thank you

Comment: First go here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then when youve tried yourself and run into specific problems come back, share your code and ask a specific question about a specific problem. Stack Overflow is here to help with problems you run into, its not here so you can get other people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

In `Message` class, you have a `reply_to_message` which returns a `Message` object and you can find user id from this object. If user doesn't reply to any message it's equal to `None`. So this is what you want: `message.reply_to_message.from_user`

If you want more information you can read from [Telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) or check [types.py](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/types.py) in library github.

Comment: could you tell more Mehdi Mostafavi?

Comment: @dayod If user A reply to User B. ```message.from_user``` contains ```User``` A information and ```message.reply_to_message.from_user``` contains ```User``` B.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict user at **least** at 30 seconds.
code to restrict:

```
bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, 
                         message.from_user.id, 
                         can_send_messages=False, 
                         until_date=int(time.time())+30)
#you can replace 30(seconds) by more.
```

unix time

Comment: thank you, user390489!
but i also need getting user id which i replied to